# What is this three-engine beauty?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What is this three-engine beauty?

[image: 3-engine aircraft]

Answer (score 17):

It appears to be a [Westland IV/Wessex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westland_IV)

I don't know why it is marked P-1, but [the elevator is distinctive](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:OO-AGC_(aircraft)#/media/File%3AWestland_Wessex_plane.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

P-1 is a temporary civilian registration issued to the company to use on prototypes. Each company was assigned a letter, so any time you see a British civilian aircraft with a letter-number code like this, it is a prototype. The best known are probably E.2 to E.3 used for the de Havilland Albatross airliners, as seen below:
[image: de Havilland Albatross airliner showing off temporary registration]

Comment: Hi Mike, the question asked it was about the type of airplane in the photograph, not so much the number on the side. That’s an interesting addendum though.

Comment: well, the sole answer was unsure of the importance of the number, and my answer added that it was a prototype Wessex, not just any Wessex.